# How to change label colour on bounding boxes in YOLOV3

Tags: yolo, darknet

I have trained yolov3 on a custom dataset following the implementation from (https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) repo. I'm getting bounding boxes for this test image but not getting labels for that. Can you please help me fix this issue?
[image]

Comment: Which code of file did you use for detection?

Comment: @AbdelAzizAbdelLatef i used  ./darknet in darknet folder to run test data

Comment: What are these black rectangles in your image?

Comment: @AbdelAzizAbdelLatef that is the problem I stated, in the place of black boxes I need to get the label names in them

Comment: You can try changing `fontScale` and `thickness` in `draw_boxes`.

Comment: @AbdelAzizAbdelLatef Sorry, but i cant find that in the mentioned repo

Comment: Here https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/darknet.py

Comment: @Thanks for taking time, the problem is solved.